# According to the values within the array key value in php

Tags: php, arrays, merge, addition

I have multiple arrays like this:

```
$value1 = array ("10" => "car", "20" => "home", "30" => "ball");
$value2 = array ("50" => "car", "60" => "home", "70" => "ball");
$value3 = array ("100" => "car", "110" => "home", "120" => "ball");
```

Now I want to merge those arrays by the value and while merging adding the key values together.

Pseudo code:

```
$endvalue = $value1 + $value2 + $value3;

print_r ($endvalue);
```

Expected output:

```
"160" => "car"
"190" => "home"
"220" => "ball"
```

I have a database like this;

```
name    facebookCount   tweetCount   googleCount

 car    20              50           100
home    50              60           10
ball    30              10           70
```

.. and I want to find the most shared value..

Like;

car  (20 + 50 + 100)

home (50+ 60 + 10)

ball (30 + 10 + 70)

..and list

car > home > ball

Can you help me ?

Comment: And what do you do when you get two duplicate keys? You can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: I have a database like;

name    -    facebookcount    -    tweetcount    -    googlecount

car                    20                            50                      100
home                50                            60                        10
home                30                            10                        70 

..and I want to learn in total up to the number of names

Comment: PHP can't have duplicate keys in an array. So you have to think about what you want to do when this occurs.

Comment: I share my database model. You can examine

Comment: Why not selecting the sums directly from your database? Do you use SQL? Can you show the query you do?

Comment: please can you show me the query you do?

Comment: Eh... it is you who does the query, right?  Can you add it to your question?

Comment: I dont understand you. I will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for input arrays with *non-duplicate keys* using `array_values`, `array_combine` and `array_search` functions:

```
...
$arrList = [$value1, $value2, $value3];  // wrapping input arrays with outer array
$names = array_combine(array_values($value1), array_fill(0, count($arrList), 0));  // getting base names list

foreach ($names as $k => &$num) {
    foreach ($arrList as $arr) {
        $num += (int) array_search($k, $arr);
    }
}

print_r($names);
```

**I believe that the final array should be an associative array, cause there could be cases when the total sums will be the same among grouped names**

The output:

```
Array
(
    [car] => 160
    [home] => 190
    [ball] => 220
)
```

Comment: But you'll get into problems when the counts are the same for facebook and twitter.

Comment: @trincot, what do you mean?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, it is not really your fault, but there is a fault in the structure design that the OP starts with, for if the values were like this: `array ("10" => "car", "10" => "home", "10" => "ball");` the array would in fact only look like `array ("10" => "ball");` which will not be the desired input (and thus also your correct algorithm will give wrong results).

Comment: @trincot, yes, I confirm that my solution is for input arrays with *non-duplicate keys*.

Comment: @serhatgksu, as for database level, you should try to get sum for each name by executing a query like `select <name_column>, SUM(<number_column>) from <table_name> GROUP BY <name_column>`

Comment: I would flip the initial value arrays, so you do not need to do a `array_search` , but can just get the amount by key. Otherwise, nice answer

Answer (score 2):

An SQL solution would probably be faster in your case, and it is in fact very simple. Simple arithmetic is no problem for SQL.

Consider a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `social` (
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `facebook` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `twitter` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `google` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
);
```

Then this query:

```
SELECT name, (facebook + twitter + google) as shares FROM social
ORDER BY shares DESC
```

Gives you the following result:

```
name    shares
car     170
home    120
ball    110
```

Not much to explain I guess, but feel free to ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.